# Match one column value with multiple value of other tables's multiple column and get all value (possible outcomes)

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables having two different table. I want to match the first table column value with other table columns values. If the first column value matches with multiple values of other get the all id's (primary key).

First table name

- fh_lead

2nd table name

- Agent
- 1st table has column `postcode`
  -2nd table has 5 columns postcode1, postcode2, postcode3, postcode4, postcode4.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.postcode
FROM fh_lead AS l
JOIN agent AS a ON ( a.postcode1 = l.postcode OR 
                     a.postcode2 = l.postcode OR 
                     a.postcode3 = l.postcode OR 
                     a.postcode4 = l.postcode OR 
                     a.postcode4 = l.postcode)
```